# I can't write command for authors' name and email addresses etc. Article Format in Latex-For Portugaliae Mathematica

Tags: templates, addresses

I had a problem When I wrote article to journal(Portugaliae Mathematica) I think,I can't find right command in latex template.I can't see authors' name,email address in pdf-file.

my .tex file has the following contents:

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Beginning of example.tex
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% LaTeX sample file for PORTUGALIAE MATHEMATICA
%
%
% NOTE: In order to use this file you need the class file pm.cl which should
% located in the same directory as this file.
%
%
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Author's Adresse(s)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%% Use this for your address{es)
%%%%%%%%%% they will appear at the end of your article
%%%%%%%%%% use one \address[]{} for each author

\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Theorem like environments
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Uncomment the next line if you would like your equations to be numbered according to sections:
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title and author(s)'s name(s)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you point to a web page with the instructions about submissions to Portugaliae Mathematica?

Comment: Thank you. http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/authorinfo.php?jrn=pm

Comment: there is a sample tex in this web page however I can't write authors' name,can't use    \address []{}   command.

Comment: `example.tex` starts with `\documentclass{PM}`, not `article`.

Comment: (1) Why did you edit out the example `\address` and `\author` fields from the example tex file? (2) Why aren't you using the `PM` documentclass?

Comment: Your document -- which, for some reason, doesn't load the `PM` document class -- doesn't have `\title`, `\author`, `\date`, and `\maketitle` directives. How is it supposed to generate title- and author-related output?

Comment: I can use latex,but I don't make good use of latex rigt now. I wonder how the software is used

Comment: my request is to learn some commands which used for title,authors,addresses,email in PM template.

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)

Comment: thanks to all, I can't deal with the problem, but I have tried to do

Comment: @acommand38  Usually `\title` do nothing per se, as well as   `\author`, etc. .  This type of the commands in the preamble simply take the information for their later use  in `\maketitle`, that take care or print all the information in the correct order (first the title, then the authors, etc ...  even when in your code \author is above \title.)  and may in  others commands for another places of the document  (headers, end of the article, etc.).